# print entered integer from input integer to integer

Tags: java

I am trying to obtain two integers as input, and then use these to output another list of integers, using the input as arguments in a loop.

In my code, if I enter low as 1, and high as 10 I expect my output should be the integers 1 through 10. However my code prints the value 1 ten times. I have tried different loops with no luck. Can someone please point out why my output is not as expected?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter the low number: ");
     int low = input.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Enter the high number: ");
     int high = input.nextInt();

     //int num1 = low
     //int num2 = high

     System.out.println("Decimal");

     for(int i = low ; low <= high; low++)


     System.out.println(i);


            }
   }
```

Comment: What is expected and what is current output ?

Comment: so i enter a low number and then a high number. it prints numbers low through high. so if i enter 1 as low and 10 as high it should print 1-10. it prints 10 1's right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that in your for loop you are incrementing the value of low with `low++` but you're printing `i` which you only set to the value of `low` at the beginning; `i` doesn't get reset to the value of `low` on every iteration in your for loop.

So, try changing `low++` to `i++` and see if that makes a difference ;)

You'll also want to change `low <= high` to `i <= high` as we are now incrementing `i`.

Comment: If it's correct - would you mind marking it so? Thanks :)